# "Required" tag not working the first time

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website that I've included a small form in. It simply asks for Email, Name and a small comment box.

I added it a few days ago and saw that people would randomly click it and I would receive empty submissions in my inbox.

Now, I've added a 'required' tag on all three HTML elements. That works... but only after the first attempt goes through...

Can any explain why that would be?

I've included the code for your review:

```
<form action="contactform.php" method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nameofclient">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameofclient" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Questions/Concerns</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" name="comment" rows="3" required></textarea>
                </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: can you reproduce the problem here in a snippet? because i couldn't reproduce it. Everything seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var form = document.getElementById('theForm');
  form.button.onclick = function (){
    for(var i=0; i < form.elements.length; i++){
      if(form.elements[i].value === '' && form.elements[i].hasAttribute('required')){
        alert('There are some required fields!');
        return false;
      }
    }
    form.submit();
  }; 
};
```

```html
<form action="contactform.php" method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nameofclient">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameofclient" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Questions/Concerns</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" name="comment" rows="3" required></textarea>
                </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

the above code might help